# Error: `pyodbc.drivers()` returns empty list inside VSCode

Tags: python, sql, visual-studio-code, odbc, pyodbc

I followed [Microsoft instructions for installing its ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17) and prepared a conda environment with the necessary packages to work with azure SQL database with Python, including `pyodbc`. I used the instructions for Ubuntu because I'm on Linux Mint 20 and well, that option isn't available (and Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu).

Then I prepared a small script to connect to a test azure database that I created:

```
import pyodbc

configString = (
    f'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    f'SERVER={server};'
    'PORT=1433;'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'UID={username};'
    f'PWD={password}'
)

with pyodbc.connect(configString) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 3 name, collation_name FROM sys.databases')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + ' ' + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

This fails with the error `('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`.
But the file exists, and if I run this from just a terminal (instead of from within VSCode) it works fine.

Also, `pyodbc.drivers()` resturns `[]` from within VSCode but it returns the correct value `['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']` when called from a Python shell within a terminal.

So the question is: why `pyodbc` fails to get the drivers from within VSCode but gets the correct values from a terminal?

Comment: Is VSCode using a Python virtual environment (venv)?

Comment: @GordThompson a conda environment. I don't know the exact differences between a conda environment and a virtual environment (venv), but from my perspective they behave the same way.